# Trying to make a shape from more shapes (see in pic) Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to make a shape (it's for hair). I colored this part with blue for clarity, all anchor points are intersected and I don't know which tool I can use to get that form as a complete figure for moving it , fill or anything else (shape builder tool doesn't recognize it and if I am trying to fill it,  it does but weird, not like a shape. Any suggestions?

Question 2: For mug is the same thing, I want mug to be one shape so I can fill items differently

[image: Part i want to get]

[image: Wreid fill, idk why]

Comment: ?Shape builder?

Comment: With shape builder i can't select that corner( triangle ) in right of neck which is white in second picture @joojaa

Comment: Sure you can. Just select all the lines before you activate shapbuilder and adjust your gap detection settings while your at it.

Comment: Well first thing would be to *close the path*. Right now there's no closure. It's merely an open path (or paths). You need to connect the end points. Then you can move it behind the figure. (And shape builder should work better)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the squiggly lines for the hair are hanging in space.  To use the Shape Builder effectively, you need to have the lines overlap to create enclosed areas, so that you can create closed shapes, and fill them.

Afterwards, you can delete the overlapping lines you don't need by simply using subtract anchor Pen tool.

Example[image]